# Printing addresses of variables

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, memory-address

When I run this code:

```
uint8_t stackVar = 0;
void* ptr = &stackVar;
uint8_t& ref = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t&>(ptr);
std::cout << (void*)&ref << std::endl;
std::cout << ptr << std::endl;
std::cout << (void*)&stackVar << std::endl;
```

I get this output:

```
0x22fe30
0x22fe3f
0x22fe3f
```

At least in my estimation I should get the same number for all three of these statements.  What is going on here?

Comment: You are making guesses on how references are implemented

Comment: `&ref` is the address of a reference to a pointer.  Why would you expect that to be equal to the pointer itself?

Comment: I think the OP is confused in that `&` has two meanings.  The `&` in the first cout means `address-of`, not `reference`.

Answer (score 2):

`uint8_t& ref = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t&>(ptr);`

You are casting a pointer (`void*`) to a reference. This will **not** result in the same `uint8_t`, because it will make a reference to a temporary `uint8_t`, which you created out of a void pointer. And because a new `uint8_t` is created, you are getting different addresses.

Maybe you meant `uint8_t& ref = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t&>(stackVar);`

Comment: Probably he meant reinterpret_cast<uint8_t>(*ptr);

Comment: @teivaz Or that, sure :)

Comment: My problem was I did not realize that if you do a `reinterpret_cast<sometype&>(/*thing here*/)` the `thing here` has to be an actual object not a pointer.....  Thanks this helped immensely

Comment: @DarthRubik It could also be a pointer, but then you have to assign it to a pointer, not an object

Comment: @teivaz (Although you cannot `*ptr` because `ptr` is a `void*`, but I got the general idea)